# How can opposite charges neutralize so fast?

Tags: electrostatics, electricity, electric-circuits, capacitance

I saw that the two end wires of a capacitor when touched to each other neutralizes quite fast(as the flash after their contact was there only for a second), how can charges neutralize the capacitor so fast?

Comment: The charges move quite fast. The charges move slow in the sense that the "net movement" of the charges in the direction of the current is slow even though they are moving at extraordinarily high speeds, but chaotically. So when two sides of a capacitor are in direct contact they neutralize quickly.

Comment: A second is a very long time for many phenomena.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, electrons move very slowly in a typical conductor like copper: on the order of microns per second. (See Wikipedia "drift velocity".)  However, an enormous number of electrons are moving, so it takes hardly any time for enough charge to be transferred to discharge the capacitor completely.  A good analogy is to think of the wires as being pipes with huge diameter but filled with slow-moving water.  It would only take a moment to move many gallons of water.  The actual amount of charge stored in a capacitor is tiny compared to the number of electrons in a cubic millimeter of copper.